# C# Winforms: how do you set focus to a DataGridView component on a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I have a DataGridView component on a form.  How do I set the focus to this component so that it responds to arrow keys?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could:

```
dataGridView.Select();
```

or

```
dataGridView.Focus();
```

Alternatively, you could set the ActiveControl property:

```
ActiveControl = dataGridView;
```

The following text came from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx)

> Focus is a low-level method intended
>   primarily for custom control authors.
>   Instead, application programmers
>   should use the Select method or the
>   ActiveControl property for child
>   controls, or the Activate method for
>   forms.

Comment: Microsoft seems to suggest `dataGridView.Select();`

Comment: Focus(); Doesn't work for me I think .Select(); is the best

Comment: ActiveControl = dataGridView is working for me, thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

U can try with this.

```
public void SetFocusToDataEntry() 

{
_datagridview.Focus();
_datagridview.CurrentCell = _datagridview.Rows[1].Cells[2];
}
```