# How to delete DataGridView Row by pressing DeleteKey?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView on a form.

I want to delete rows from the grid by pressing the delete key, but delete key seems to be dead, until I enter into `CellEditMode`.

If I enter to `CellEditMode` then the delete key works, but obviously only for deleting cell contents, not for deleting rows.

The DataGridView has `AllowUserToDeleteRow = true` and the grid is unbound.

I have other grids where this function works correctly, but can't see the difference.

Comment: Does the datagridview on the second form have focus? It needs focus to accept the delete. Have a look at this question for help on doing that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268735/c-sharp-winforms-how-do-you-set-focus-to-a-datagridview-component-on-a-form

Comment: If my comment doesn't fix your problem then give some more exact information on how you have set things up.

Comment: Yes, my dgv has focus, i clicked and selected the rows normally, but i cannot delete them.
Please, create two forms and put a datagridview on each. Load the second form (from the first one) and try to delete a dgvRow by pressing DeleteKey.

Comment: Tried and it worked, just as one would expect. How about you post your code and we see what is wrong? Or perhaps you try opening a new instance of the main form and see if delete is broken there too.

Comment: So you only have a grid with some columns on it in the second form - absolutely nothing else? The only thing close to what you describe that I have seen is if a cell is already being edited - then when the row is selected the delete key still acts on that cell. Unless you give some more information such as the extra code you have in that second form I really doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: At the very least explain **exactly** what you do - down to each key and mouse press.

Comment: I dragged both dgvs from toolbox
So - all of my code is from buttonClick on form01:
new frm02().Show();
I tried as you said - new frm01().Show(); - and - DeleteKey works.

DeleteKey works even on frm02, but only if I enter into CellEditMode.
Do you have any idea ?
What code should I post ?
I don't do anything except open childform - click on dgvRow to select it - and press DeleteKey. Selection is ok, everything is ok - but Delete is not.

Comment: Maybe best to move this to chat. I'm in the c# room - click on the chat link at the top of this page.

Comment: Ah damn, you need 20 reputation to chat. So please edit your question with the exact setup for the problem - how you create each form, what columns you have in the form, things like that, then describe exactly what reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sorry, i have no 20 reputation:
I'm signed in yesterday.

Comment: Yes, so as I said, provide the asked for information (to your question not as a comment) - a detailed description of how to set up a sample project. A detailed description of how to reproduce the problem on the project. As it stands I have two unbound grids on different forms, I open the second form from the first and can use the delete key in the second grid to delete selected rows. It seems to me that I'm doing just what you describe so you need to explain your situation better.

Comment: form02 I created from menu: - Project - Add New Item...
Only one column on the dgv02.
All of my steps are:
Create form - drag a dgv on it - load that form from ParentForm. There are no more steps.

Comment: Please - add to your question, do not post comments with code in them. Describe exactly the steps you take once the second form is open. Where do you click? What do you expect to see happen? Do you click within the column in form 2? Do you type in there? How do you select the row? All these details are important - you have to give them.

Comment: Yes, you did exactly that.
I really have no idea - what should I describe?
My steps are - create two forms - put dgvs on each, load second form , select a dgvRow by mouse, and press DeleteKey.
Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: So how do you have data in the second form? You said it was unbound. If it unbound then it has no data in it until you enter some. Pressing the delete key won't do anything - there is nothing to delete.

Comment: I read xml node by node.
but i tried with apsolutelly empty dgv, and added content typing into cells. After that, i tried Delete - not works.

Comment: And how do you select the row? The delete key only works when the full row is selected. Do you click on the row header?

Comment: Oh, my God. You're right. SelectionMode was not - FullRow and  RowHeaders were hidden.
THANKS MAN. Once more - THANKS MAN !

Comment: No problem - might I suggest that you edit some of the detail here into the question - Question text is easier to search for so others might benefit from your question. Also, you get a bit of experience in writing excellent questions on SO which is the best way to get quick good answers. I'm also going to post an answer, please mark it as accepted - I'll vote up your question when it has some info, everyone wins :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One possible cause for the delete functionality not working is that you need to have a row selected.

This means either having the `SelectionMode` set to `FullRowSelect` or means that you have previously clicked on the row headers which are to the left of the columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `DataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter` you can't delete any row

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this is making sure "SelectionMode = FullRowSelect" and "EditMode = EditOnKeystrokeOrF2".

This makes it so when they first select the row it doesn't jump into edit mode which would require an "Esc" key press to exit edit mode then delete.

And even though the mode is called "EditOnKeystrokeOrF2", a second click on the cell will also start edit mode.