# DataGridView showing on WinForms

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have few DataGridViews with "FullRowSelection" on Form and for that reason I (like user) have to know which DGV have a focus (if any).

For that I change a color of selected row background under _GotFocus and _LostFocus handlers for each DGV (or in subclass).

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.GotFocus
    DataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.LostFocus
    DataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DarkGray
End Sub
```

Such, when DGV get a focus selected row is typical blue and when DGV lost focus selected row becames gray. That work OK but one problem is present.

When form is loaded all DGV's have blue selected row no matter if they don't have a focus.

How to get in showed situation that DGV which don't have a focus appear with gray selected row?

Comment: Set focus at load event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268735/c-sharp-winforms-how-do-you-set-focus-to-a-datagridview-component-on-a-form

Comment: I can set focus to one DGV but what with others?

Comment: Only 1 control could have focus at a given moment.

Comment: That mean that you didn't understand a question. My all DGV's have blue selected line when form is loaded and no one have a focus so I would like that they all appear with gray selected row.

Comment: Actually, I can set focus in form's _Load to every DGV, one by one and finally to wanted control and then DGV's look's a expected but I search for initial way for doing this even in DGV's subclass.

Comment: Focus the "default" control manually, i.e. `DataGridView1.Focus()`?

Comment: Can do this but I would like to find more generic, automatic solution.